# How to install nvidia driver without replace x.org.x server

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, system-installation, graphics, xorg

I am installing nvidia version 340. My ubuntu version 14.04 with kernel is 3.19.0-20-generic. My nvidia is GeForce GT 650M. I install that nvidia version because I have schedule to install CUDA 6.5 and that cuda only work for that nvidia version.I have one problem that is after installing nvidia and restart. After login. I cannot go to main GUI( It appears black screen). However, when I uninstall it. It can go to my GUI.I think that the install replace X.org X. Thus, it cannot go to GUI. Have any way to install nvidia and still using X.org X server.

This is my `dkms status`

```
bbswitch,0.7, 3.19.0-20-generic , x86_64: installed
nvidia-340, 340.76, 3.19.0-20-generic, x_86_64: installed
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you install nvidia-340, How do you install it? What is your Ubuntu version? What is your Nvidia adapter?

Comment: my ubuntu version is 3.19.0-20-generic. My nvidia is GeForce GT 650M. I install that version because I have schedule to install CUDA 6.5 and that cuda only work for that nvidia version. Thanks

Comment: It is kernel version. Ubuntu version must be 15.04. Please add this information to your question with explanation on why you picked 340.

Comment: And nothing replaces X.org. The driver does not build or work for your adapter and/or kernel version. That's the problem. I do not know anything about CUDA and can't help to install 340. Someone else may help.

Comment: And how did you install the driver? Did you install nvidia-prime? You must have hybrid graphics.

Comment: I install by command sudo apt-get install nvidia-340

Comment: nvidia-prime is already the newest version.

Comment: Try to install also nvidia-prime and are there any errors when you install the driver?

Comment: No, it is installed automaticlly

Comment: It writes something in terminal when it is installed. Did you read that? What does it mean "automatically"?

Comment: Please add output of `dkms  status` to your question.

Comment: @Pilot6: Look at my updated.

Comment: Looks good, no more ideas.

Comment: Thank Pilots. I remember that before i install opencv2.4.9, it work well. But after that, I have that problem. I uninstall nvidia and reinstall it again but problem still does not resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install a version that fixes issues with 340.

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia* 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-340 nvidia-prime nvidia-settings
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

But this is for Ubuntu 14.04 with 3.19 kernel, not 15.04.

Comment: It does not work. Sir

Comment: Were there any error messages?

Comment: I updated the answer. Forgot nvidia-prime. Try again please.

Comment: No error. But I cannot login the GUI. After login, my screen is black. Nothing

Comment: Please try again the updated commands and post output of the 4th one to your question. It can be removed later.

Comment: You can remove drivers from console. I hope you do not re-install the system every time.

Comment: Sir, It still can not go to main GUI. When I click Ctrl+Alt+F1, it show error such as "can not get freq at ep 0x82". But i think it is camera driver. It does not affect to GUI

Comment: No more ideas then, sry

Answer (score 0):

There have been a LOT of reported problems with Nvidia and the newer releases/kernels.  The suggested solutions:

1. Install the xorg-edgers/ppa version of the driver (see Pilot6's answer).  That didn't help in my case with the 304 version of the driver (the version was the same as in the standard ppa), your case may differ.
2. Install the nouveau driver.  Well, that's the default, so it should be used when there is no Nvidia stuff around.  After trying the Nvidia packages and giving up, uninstall them with

   sudo apt-get purge nvidia...
   Use repeatedly on each package, since the wildcard * may produce unwanted results.  Not for you if you really need the
   Nvidia driver. Not for people whose machine drastically overheats
   with nouveau.
3. Try "nomodeset" on the linux line in the grub boot items.  May work for some issues.  If that solves some problems, you may make it permanent by adding the word to the file /etc/default/grub on line

   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset quiet splash"
4. Get rid of unity/compiz.  This may be necessary in some machines
   which could only marginally run unity in the past.  There are many other desktop choices.  Easiest way is just to install Lubuntu, then add the Nvidia drivers. If you add the xfce4 package,

sudo apt-get install xfce4

You should be able to choose the xfce desktop at login by clicking on the little Ubuntu logo at the top of the username list.  Remove unwanted desktops with the
 `sudo apt-get purge xfce4`
 5. And the most drastic solution, drop back to a release which works
    with Nvidia, like the 12.04 with the original 3.2 kernel.  Download the original 12.04 iso, not the later ones like 12.04.5 which are using the later kernels.  Do the usual create install media, and install it (backing up first of course).

The easiest solutions are just trying another release, like Lubuntu or Ubuntu 12.04.  The forums are a better place for back and forth help which will probably be needed here, since there seems to be no one clean solution.

Comment: Could you show me the command in ubuntu. Thanks so much

Comment: Bad method. i installl xfce4 but it does not go to my previous GUI. It went to its GUI. I remove by sudo apt-get remove xfce4 but it does not removed. How to remove it? Thanks